# How to show vertical TEXT using plotly js?

Tags: javascript, plotly

Using plotly, how can I show this text vertically?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I'd say "show us some code" but the drawing totally compensates for it.

The main feature need here is [`textangle`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-annotations-textangle) to specify the rotation in degrees. Just add an `annotation`, hide the `arrow` (`showarrow: false`) and set the `x/y` positions.

```js
Plotly.plot('myDiv', [{
  x: [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10],
  y: [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10]
}], {
  annotations: [{
    x: 6.75,
    y: 7.25,
    text: 'Vertical',
    textangle: '-55',
    showarrow: false
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv' width=300 height=300></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Maximilian Peters but my issue is not solved..annotations not working inside trace...how to use annotations inside trace?

Comment: You can't use annotations inside a trace, they are separate objects. Is 'Date' in your example the axis label?

Comment: Hey Maximilian Peters my issue is resolved thanks for your help..and i have few doubts in plotly js can u help me??

Comment: Just post a minimal example, your expected outcome and your attempt and I am sure there will someone to answer your question.

Comment: I used the above to help me with some stacked barcharts in a trace. The text angle was what I needed.